# Weird Screenshot and downloads

Tags: samsung, cache

I have a Samsung J3 something... Its thru virgen.

At least once a day my phone freezez then the screen turns black then comes back to normal. Then when I go to my gallery a "file" or "cache" is visible with what looks like a screenshot of my screen. I also have every sticker icon from facebook stickers downloaded into my gallery. I end up having to delete all these icons.

CAN SOMEONE TELL ME WHATS GOING ON? Am I hacked? Is it a glitch? Any feed back will be appreciated.

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshots (click images to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Your phone is not hacked. Try clearing cache and reboot your phone. It should then act normally.

Comment: This doesn't explain how come stickers from Facebook end up downloaded automatically into Galler.

Comment: It looks like the directory containing Facebook stickers doesn't have .nomedia file inside it, resulting in stickers appearing in the gallery. Don't know what causes freezes tho.

Comment: This makes sense because I go into my FILES and are constantly cleaning up files. I delete all folders that look like nothing important. Ill keep that folder in my files. Thank you.

Comment: Ok... ive done that. Ive even gone into facebook stickers and - them. There still showing upand that .cache image still shows up. IM NOT PHONE SAVY, but please help me. It freezes up my phone for a minute or two then all these stickers show up in my drive and gallery.it can be over 50 images of those damn facebook stickers i added for free... i hate this